# Generic benchmark of opening/closing programs

Tags: c#, .net, process, benchmarking

I'm trying to create a generic C# method that can benchmark the opening and closing of applications to compare this performance across test systems (we have a program in our environment that interferes with application startups for security reasons, and we want an automated method of testing its impact). This is what I have currently for my tester class:

```
public class ApplicationBenchmarker
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; private set; }
    public string ApplicationPath { get; private set; }

    public List<long> msOpenTimes { get; private set; } = new List<long>();

    public ApplicationBenchmarker(string applicationName, string applicationPath)
    {
        ApplicationName = applicationName;
        ApplicationPath = applicationPath;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Application " + ApplicationName + " starting...");


        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        Process process = Process.Start(ApplicationPath);
        process.WaitForInputIdle();
        process.CloseMainWindow();
        process.WaitForExit();
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Application " + ApplicationName + " exited.");
        msOpenTimes.Add(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Testing this across some applications, I get this behavior:

- Notepad.exe - The code appears to work as intended, opening up the program, and then closing it, waiting for the close to record the time.
- IE.exe - The code opens IE, but never closes IE. It thinks it did close, however, and stops the stopwatch while IE is still open.
- EXCEL.EXE (Office 365, current branch) - The code opens Excel, but never closes it. The code hangs waiting for it to close.

Is there a better way I can recreate the generic behavior of benchmarking the open/close time?

Comment: Why don't you just kill the process if it doesn't close itself?

Comment: @KfirGuy I want to gracefully exit as it should only be able to gracefully exit once it finishes opening and frees up the thread. Just calling process.Kill() is just benchmarking how fast Windows can kill a process.

Comment: And what if you wait for it to finish opening and then kill it?

Comment: @KfirGuy Well for EXCEL.exe it doesn't ever see it as open. With IE.exe and it thinking it closes, it implies there's a more intrinsic problem, like I'm not actually capturing (correct) information about the process, which means my benchmark ms measurement won't be correct.